# Getting the amplitude and phase of harmonics in C

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, transform

I have a periodic series of 360 values. How can I use the fftw c libraries to get the amplitude and phase of the first, second, third and fourth harmonic?

If I do this for N=360

```
fftw_plan_r2r_1d(N,input_array,output_array,FFTW_R2HC,FFTW_ESTIMATE);
```

I can get the 360-point Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) where output_array is complex Hermitian in **half-complex** format.

Where k$^{th}$ component of output_array is the real part and (N-k)$^{th}$ component of output_array is the imaginary part.

So if I want the amplitude or magnitude(??) of the first harmonic should I do this?

```
ampl_1sth=sqrt(output_array[1]*output_array[1]+output_array[N-1]*output_array[N-1])
```

Is that correct? then the amplitude of the second harmonic will be the same but with output_array[2] and output_array[N-2] and so on right?

And then how can I get the phase of the first, second, third and fourth harmonic with the info from the DFT?

For a reference to fftw see here www.fftw.org/fftw3.pdf

Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224874/using-fftw-c-libraries-to-get-amplitude-and-phase-of-first-4-harmonics

Comment: Also not to forget about k=0 and k=n/2 (even) for DC and Nyquist bin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to know how to compute magnitude and phase of a complex number $z=z_R+iz_I$:

$$|z|=\sqrt{z_R^2+z_I^2}\\
\arg\{z\}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}0,&z_R=z_I=0\\
\pi/2&z_R=0,\; z_I>0\\
-\pi/2&z_R=0,\; z_I<0\\
\arctan\left(\frac{z_I}{z_R}\right),&z_R>0\\
\arctan\left(\frac{z_I}{z_R}\right)+\pi,&z_R<0,\;z_I\ge0\\
\arctan\left(\frac{z_I}{z_R}\right)-\pi,&z_R<0,\;z_I<0\\
\end{array}\right.
$$

Luckily, the computation of the phase $\arg\{z\}$ is simplified by the existence of the function [atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) in most programming languages. Watch out, you need to use it like this:

$$\text{phase = }\text{atan2}(z_I,z_R)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt. So if I want the amplitude and phase of the second harmonic I would have to just make those calculations with hc[2] and hc[N-2] right? In my case.

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

So if I want to calculate for example the `fifth_harmonic` (phase + amplitude) for every point in the time domain, I have to write:

```
fifth_harmonic[k] = ampl_5th * cos((5 * PI * k)/N-1 + phase_5th)
```

or

```
fifth_harmonic[k] = ampl_5th * sin((5 * PI * k)/N-1 + phase_5th)
```

?

where:

`K=0,......,N-1` are the sampling point in time domain

`fifth_harmonic` - amplitude for the fifth harmonic

`phase_5th`  - phase for the fifth harmonic

which one I have to use: the sin or cos?

Comment: Is correct to say that if you expect a real output you have to use the cosin component? Otherwise yo have to use a combination of both cosin and sin component?